# Why do we need to keep the solution of the homogeneous equation in the general equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, singular-solution

On the theme of differential equations, I wonder why we still need to keep the solution of the homogeneous equation.

For example the linear differential equation :

$y' + ay = x^2   \enspace \enspace \enspace (E)$

$y' + ay = 0   \enspace \enspace \enspace (H)$

After resolving the homogeneous equation $(H)$, we get a first solution $y_h$ :

$y_h = k.e^{-ax}$

And after applying the Lagrange method, we resolve :

$ x^2 = k'(x) e^{-ax} \Longleftrightarrow  k'(x)= x^2 e^{ax}  $

$ k(x) = \int_{}^x t^2 e^{at} dt$

$k(x) = \Bigl(\frac{a^2x^2 - 2ax + 2}{a^3}\Bigr) e^{ax} $

So we get a particular solution $ y_0 $ as :

$ y_0 = k(x) e^{-ax} \Longleftrightarrow y_0 = \frac{a^2x^2 - 2ax + 2}{a^3} $

Now, we can verify that $ y_0 $ is conform with $(E)$ injecting $y_0$ and $y_0'$, which is the case.

So, why we have to say that the general solution is the sum of both solutions ($y_t = y_h + y_0$), whereas the solution $y_0$ works without adding $y_h$ ?

Here, i would be :

$y_t = y_h + y_0$

$y_t = k.e^{-ax} +\frac{a^2x^2 - 2ax + 2}{a^3} $

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you may see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886718/dif-eq-general-solution-is-sum-of-homogeneous-and-particular-solutions). Next, I will point to **Superposition Principle**: If $y_1$ is a solution to the equation $ay'+by=f_1(x)$ and $y_2$ is a solution to $ay'+by=f_2(x)$, then for any constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, the function $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ is a solution to the differential equation $ay'+by=c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)$.

Comment: Let's suppose that you want a solution to $y'+ay=x^2$ that also satisfies the condition $y(0)=0$. Can you solve this problem using only the particular solution $y_0$?

Comment: Because the differential equations are **linear**, the *difference* between any two solutions of the full differential equation will be a solution to the homogenous equation:$$L(y_1) = f\\L(y_2) = f\\\implies L(y_2 - y_1) = f - f = 0$$ It is usually more difficult to solve the full equation than the homogenous equation. so if you can find any single solution to the full equation, and the general solution to the homogenous equation, summing them gives you the general solution to the full equation.